# A shell script to read the content of the file under folders and write them into a text file

Tags: shell, scripting

I have 53000 folders (named as numbers 1,2,3 ...) inside each of which there is a single file called "prop". I need to collect the data from them into a single text file. I used that command. But Some of the folders have a blank "prop" file. I need to know which are blank in my text file.

```
#!/bin/sh
a=0
while [ $a - le 53000]
do 
a= 'expr $a + 1'
cat $a/prop >> x.txt
done
```

Comment: And what info do you want to add to the `x.txt` file when there is not files inside the folder?

Comment: I have the same question as @higuaro plus this one: first you said: `I have 53000 folders (named as numbers 1,2,3 ...) inside *each* of which there is a single file called "prop"`, but later you said: `But Some of the folders have no "prop" file.` - so do all folders have a `prop` file or only some of them?

Comment: sorry, some of them has a blank "prop" file

Comment: The question states "Some of the folders have no "prop" file."  It also states "I need to know which are blank."  Those are two very different things.  When you say "blank," do you mean that the file exists but has no content or that the file does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

This will copy the contents of all the existing `prop` files to `x.txt`.  This will also put messages detailing any missing files in `missing.txt`:

```
cat {1..53000}/prop >x.txt 2>missing.txt
```

If, for example, the file `515/prop` was missing, then there will be a line in `missing.txt` stating:

```
cat: 515/prop: No such file or directory
```

This requires `bash` or any other advanced shell that supports brace expansion.

Answer (score 0):

From the directory with the numbered folders in it, you can [look for directories that don't contain your specific file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196960/find-directories-that-dont-contain-a-file#196966) with

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d '!' -exec test -e "{}/prop" ';' -print
```

Example:

```
 ls *
1:
prop

2:
prop

3:


$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d '!' -exec test -e "{}/prop" ';' -print
./3
```